# Does SSRS Reportviewer control have a directory browse function?

Tags: asp.net, ssrs-2008-r2

After looking into deploying SSRS as an internet facing service (and the unexpected complexity of it) I've come across the ReportViewer control.

All of the tutorials I've seen have the datasets being populated by code.

Is is possible to get a listing of existing reports in a given directory? And to execute them? I'd like to make some of the reports public but not all.

Comment: The ReportViewer displays reports, it isn't a browser for existing reports. What you ask is what the SSRS Report Manager site does.

Comment: Thanks - I can discount this as an option - I've looked at the docs on deploying it in a extranet environment - what's your advice on the complexity of this?

Comment: On what? What is the question and what do you want to do? ReportViewer is a *Report Viewer*. You are asking how to create, a menu structure? A tree view? Something else? With data based on what? The folder structure in the Report Server? Some other hierarchy? That's no different than creating any other menu, tree view, list view etc. First, find/retrieve your data, then bind it to your controls.

Comment: SSRS exposes a SOAP web Service. You can use it to get a list of all reports. This is explained in [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36029587/does-ssrs-reportviewer-control-have-a-directory-browse-function?noredirect=1#comment59709791_36029587)

Comment: Sorry to be ambiguous - all of my reports and data and directory structure are in place on my ReportServer - and I'm trying to avoid having to code for everything when it's in place already. Your SOAP comment goes back to this question - could you replace the link please?